# Virtual lab using Vmware

Tags: virtual-machine, dns, vmware, static-ip

I am trying to create a virtual lab using Microsoft server 2016 as DNS server and 3 Client virtual machines (Windows 10, Windows 7 & Kali Linux). and i gave them the below static IP v4

[Windows Server 2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbPaJ.png)

[client machines Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOUGv.png)

the same IP settings for machines Windows 10 with IP: 192.168.1.200 and for Kali 192.168.1.199

All the machines were able to ping each other but they did not have internet connection. what is the reason and how can i fix it. Note that the virtual machine are on VMware Workstation Pro and the lan sittings for all of them is Bridged

Answer (score 0):

though it was configured static on your servers, did you also did the "DHCP Reservation" for those clients on your router? 
Tried to disable firewall on your client machines?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Win2016 server able to connect to the Internet? It has a DNS in the different 172.0.0.0 network.

1. Can the Win server connect to that DNS at 172.0.0.1?
2. What does mean, no connection to the Internet?

   - Can the Win server ping to 8.8.8.8?
   - I assume it can't ping to google.com, am I right?
   - If so, your Win DNS server can't resolve names because it don't have connection to the DNS at 172.0.0.1
3. Can the clients ping to 8.8.8.8?
4. Can you do a `nslookup`?

   - first at 172.0.0.1, I think names can't be resolved.
   - if you change with `server 8.8.8.8` then, could names be resolved?